# AES MODE_CFB decoding result is different

Tags: java, python, spring, aes, crypt

**python code**

```
    from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES as domeAES
           def __init__(self, key):
           self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()
           self.block_size = cryptoAES.block_size

           def decrypt(self, enc):
                passphrase = self.key
                base64.b64encode(passphrase)
        
                encrypted = base64.b64decode(enc)
                IV = encrypted[:self.block_size]
                aes = domeAES.new(passphrase, domeAES.MODE_CFB, IV)
                enc = aes.decrypt(encrypted[self.block_size:])
```

**JAVA CODE**

```
 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] passphrase = md.digest(secretkey.getBytes());
            SecretKey keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(passphrase, "AES");
            byte[] encrypted = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sdata.getBytes());
            byte[] encryptedSelfBlockSize = selfBlockSize(encrypted);

            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, iv, 0, iv.length);

            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            String test = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptedSelfBlockSize));

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivSpec);
            byte[] aes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedSelfBlockSize);
```

*I proceeded in the same way, why are the values ​​different?*

My thoughts are below.

java code (byte[] aes) == python code (enc)

Comment: In your Java code, you pass your secretkey into SHA-256 message digest and then use it as the passphrase while you didn't do that in Python. Is that intentional?

Comment: This is the intended part.
Python also uses keys like this                                                                                
         self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()

Comment: It could be a good idea to present a full sample dataset (origin plaintext, key, initialization vector and ciphertext) to check any implementation.

Comment: Topaco : With your help, the code has been solved.